# React iFrame createPortal doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: reactjs, firefox, iframe

I'm trying to render JSX content inside an iFrame using createPortal. It works fine in Edge, Chrome, but in Firefox the iframe body stays empty. My React version is 17.0.2 Here's the component:

````
export class IFrame extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      mountNode: null
    }
    this.setContentRef = (contentRef) => {
      this.setState({mountNode: contentRef?.contentWindow?.document?.body})
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { children, ...props } = this.props
    const { mountNode } = this.state
    return (
      <iframe
        {...props}
        ref={this.setContentRef}
      >
        {mountNode && createPortal(children, mountNode)}
      </iframe>
    )
  }
}```

And then rendering it:
```<IFrame><div>test</div></IFrame>```
Firefox stays blank, other browsers are showing "test" as intended.

Any idea why would that be?
````

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser console in Firefox?

Comment: No error in Firefox console

Comment: @emilevirus did you solve this or find a workaround? Facing the same issue, although I am using Preact.

Comment: @DaniFernandez Yes, here's the workaround: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/22847#issuecomment-991394558

Answer (score 1):

Using an `onLoad` handler instead of using `ref` solves the issue in Firefox 118.0.1 (64-bit) macOS Apple Silicon.

```js
import React, { ReactNode, useState } from 'react'
import { createPortal } from 'react-dom'

type Props = {
  children?: ReactNode
}

export const IFrame = (props: Props) => {
  const [iframeBody, setIframeBody] = useState<HTMLElement | null>(null)

  return (
    <iframe onLoad={(event) => {
        const iframe = event.target as HTMLIFrameElement
        if (!iframe?.contentDocument) return
        setIframeBody(iframe?.contentDocument.body)
      }}>
      {iframeBody && createPortal(props.children, iframeBody)}
    </iframe>
  )
}
```