# React createPortal not rendering component inside iframe properly

Tags: reactjs, iframe, react-hooks, react-portal

I have a React component using the `iframe` element along with `createPortal`.

```
import React, {ReactNode, useState} from 'react'
import { createPortal } from 'react-dom'

type Props = {
    children?: ReactNode
}

export const IFrame = (props: Props) => {
    const [ref, setRef] = useState<HTMLIFrameElement | null>()
    const container = ref?.contentDocument?.body
    
    return (
        <iframe ref={setRef}>
            {container && createPortal(props.children, container)}
        </iframe>
    )
}
```

I can use the `IFrame` component with another component.

```
<IFrame><div>Hello, World!</div></IFrame>
```

But what I see inside the iframe when it renders, is only a breif flash with the text `Hello, World!` before it disappears.

Why is the iframe removing the content after render?

Here is the React versions I am using:

```
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
```

Comment: I tried using the code above in Safari and Chrome, and it works fine. It seems this is a problem related to Firefox. See [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70158165/react-iframe-createportal-doesnt-work-in-firefox) for more information.